# What gadget does Will have on his wrist in "Stranger Things" S03E08?

Tags: props, stranger-things

Here are two screenshots from *Stranger Things* S03E08 with the gadget in question:

[image: wristwatch-style gadget depicting a triangle of sorts]

[image: same as above, angle slightly different]

It does not look like a wrist watch. Is it maybe some kind of portable video game?

Comment: Close voters: I honestly can't see why you try to close good questions with valid answers, that get positive feedback (aka upvotes). Sure, it's trivia. but it's **interesting** and adding "color" to the site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard agreed. This is happening more and more across the stack sites. It’s becoming a problem.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan dunno about other sites, yeah... meta is the place to discuss this but I'm afraid most people on this site don't ever visit meta.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a Nelsonic Q'Bert Wristwatch, sold by [Nelsonic Digital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelsonic_Industries). They were very popular, especially in the 80s for their game-themed wristwatches, wherein you could actually play the game on your wrist!

[image]

Source:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelsonic_Industries

Comment: I had the [Tetris game watch](http://www.handheldmuseum.com/Nelsonic/Tetris.htm) in the early 90s. Did not realise I was missing out on the Q*bert option.

Comment: wonder how they afforded that

Comment: @NigelFds That’s a 1983 model watch on his wrist in 1985. Easily could have been found on sale.